# Difference between PostBPMNParseListeners and PreBPMNParseListeners

Tags: camunda, business-process-management

While reading about BPMNParseListeners, I noticed 2 different implementations using PostBPMNParseListeners and PreBPMNParseListeners, what is the difference between these two ?

Does this just indicate the sequence of execution of the listeners ? like triggering the listener before or after parsing the BPMN based on which ParseListener has been used.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. The parse listeners are a very flexible tool, which could be used for various, possibly unforeseen things. Having the option to execute code before the engine is parsing the BPMN (PreBPMNParseListeners) and after it does so (PostBPMNParseListeners) opens the door for various engine plugins.

There is also the AbstractBpmnParseListener.

Some examples here:
https://github.com/camunda-consulting/camunda-7-code-examples/blob/master/snippets/bpmn-parse-listener-on-call-activity/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/example/parselistener/CallActivityBusinessKeyParseListener.java

https://github.com/camunda-consulting/camunda-7-code-examples/tree/master/snippets/email-incident-handler-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please guide me with the specific uses cases of both PreBPMNParseListeners and PostBPMNParseListeners. In what scenarios do we need to use them ?

Comment: These options are very generic is nature and rarely use. They would allow you to perform modifications to the BPMN either before or after it was parsed, for instance replace some placeholders in the model or automatically add additional model elements, whcih you don't want to model manually. If you are asking, then you probably don't need them. What is your use case? What are you trying to achieve? 
If it answers your question, please accept my answer.